# Ruby - Watir - PhantomJS

Tags: ruby, linux, phantomjs, watir

I'm on debian.  I have ruby set up with bundle.  I do

```
sudo gem install watir-webdriver
sudo gem install phantomjs
```

Then I add both to my Gemfile.  Then I do bundle install.  Then I run ruby code

```
Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)
```

and get this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.rb:38:in `executable_path': Unable to find phantomjs executable. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

How do I make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you don't have phantomjs installed correctly (or at all), so when your program tries to open phantomjs, it cant find it.

try this
http://www.netdip.com/install-phantomjs-1422766836/

Comment: That page is 404.

Answer (score 1):

You may install phantomjs as a [gem](https://github.com/avaynshtok/phantomjs-binaries).